# How to use a query in C# (not web)?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have created a database in microsoft office access. In `form1.cs` i added a `DataGridView` with the source from the database created. In `tableDataSet.xsd/tabelAdapter` i created a new query with 3 parameters which i use to insert the data in the database `( Name, Password, Age)` . how can i use this query with that 3 parameters from 3 different `textbox`?

PS: i use only Windows Form Application, no asp.net or etc.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace lucian
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'jucatoriDataSet.jucator' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.jucatorTableAdapter.Fill(this.jucatoriDataSet.jucator);

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void adaugareToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.jucatorTableAdapter.Fill(this.jucatoriDataSet.jucator);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at that article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163709.aspx 
Basically you need to learn about ADO.NET :)

Comment: Or Entity framework may be nhibernate or some other ORM i am not aware currently